# main.CRITICAL: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly. magento2

Tags: magento2

When purchasing from the checkout form in Arabic language, this error gives me

```
main.CRITICAL: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly."vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:270)
```

But in English language work fine. How to solve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade 2.4.2 i see several fixes applied on 2.4.2 related with Arabic language. You can see also 2.4.2 release notes.